# How does one install man pages for C libraries on Linux?

Tags: c, manpage, libusb-1.0

I recently installed libusb-1.0-dev in Debian, but I noticed that I can't find any of the functions in the man pages.  I've had a similar experience when installing SDL2 and other common libraries before.  However, I can't find **any** information on how to install man pages other than for the C standard library and OS-level information. What is the correct way to install man pages for common libraries such as libusb-1.0?

Comment: After you install a package that installs man pages to either `/usr/share/man/manX` or `/usr/local/share/man/manX`, you need to change to root and run `mandb` so the man database index is updated to include the new pages. That said, this question is more appropriate on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You have a good question, but you have posted to the wrong StackEachange site. I’m voting to close this question because your question is not "Programming" related, it is more appropriate for the StackExchange site [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: debian likes to keep the documentation packages separated.  Try installing  libusb-1.0-doc

Answer (score 0):

Documentation is (often) in a different package:

`sudo aptitude install libusb-1.0-doc`